# Windows Installation Problem

Tags: windows-xp, installation

My System is behaving strange. When trying to Install Windows (XP, 2003) it get hanged during the setup stage where it says "Windows is Copying Files...". To analyze, I tried different tests (Swapping RAM sticks, Different CD-ROM and Windows Disk, Resetting CMOS etc) but same headache, it gets freezes.

BUT I tried Linux (Ubuntu) and it gets install easily and I need Windows for this machine.

Any clues please, for Windows?

Comment: It's possible something is wrong with the windows disk.

Comment: Kyle, I tested the Windows Disk on a different PC and it works just fine. Can it be motherboard or hard disk problem? but how come Ubuntu worked then... :(

Comment: Is this a fresh install? Are you booting from disk or installing from an OS already loaded?

Comment: @ngen, I am trying to install a fresh copy of Windows. I boot from Disk and then format. I tried NTFS and FAT both with new and fresh partitions as well).

Comment: If you have any unnecessary devices connected, try disconnecting them for the install process (example: floppy drive). If you don't mind, can you post your computer spec for the failing Windows XP installation.

Comment: @ngen, it's Intel P4, 180 GB Disk, AsRock motherboard (Micro ATX P4i65G). nothing very special but it used to be my server with Win 2003 for testing ASP.NET apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it was:

A) An hd failure.

Windows couldn't install but ubuntu did it perfectly.

Test your hd with any live cd distro or minipe or diagnostic cd :)

B) Dead windows cd: try it on another pc

Comment: Pitto let's say it's the hard drive as faulty but how come Ubuntu works fine...(Although Ubuntu didn't detect the Internet connection at the end but else everything went smooth and fast).

Comment: I really don't know! Probably it recognizes bad sectors and avoid them? I don't have any technical accurate answer but I can tell you that I've tried both windows xp and windows 7 from perfect media and didn't have success. Ubuntu did it! :O

Comment: Well upto now I have tried every possible step except the Hard drive. Seems like the bad guy is Hard drive :)

Comment: Use hiren boot cd or anything similar and find it out :)

Good hunt!

Answer (score 2):

This could be a driver problem.

Windows is maybe missing a driver for the hard disk, while Ubuntu is missing one for network adapter.

More information about the hard disk, manufacturer and model, would be useful.

Comment: Good point but... In that case how could partitioning and format be achievable?

Comment: The disk model is Western Digital Caviar WD800, Jumper settings are CS (Cable select).

Comment: This is a very old 80GB IDE model from 2002, which requires no driver. It did well to survive up until 2010. The difference between Windows and Linux is maybe their usage of the disk. It is time to get a new disk.

Comment: If the computer has the same age as the disk, it may not be worth more investment. It is a good computer that lasts 8 years.